# AD B2C Single Logout with Subdomain

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, azure-ad-b2c

I am using Tenant based 4 applications Azure AD B2C Single Sign On.

Applications are registered in common Tenant.

When One application Sign IN then rest of then application needs not to signIn it automatically signin when request in same browser separate tab.

When Try to Logout from One application then it can not work for rest of the applications in same browser.

When try to refresh other open applications then their session is working. they did not go to sign-in.

Single Logout is not working.

Any Advice.

Expecting Single Logoff will work for other applications registered in same Tenant.
When logoff from one application.
then on Refresh second tab, another application should be sign off and needs to signin again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When one application make Logoff then needs to close Browser. All shared cookies are removed. When one app is logoff and another app keeps its cookies in same Browser when Refresh in Second app in same Browser with different Tab then it can not logoff automatically. Needs to Close the Browser.

Then it works fine.